# Unable to sniff Bluetooth communication on iOS devices using Bluefruit LE.Why?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sniffing, ios-bluetooth

I am using the Adafruit Bluefruit LE sniffer to try to capture the bluetooth traffic between my iphone 6 and pebble watch. The sniffer for some reason is not able to identify any iOS(iphone 5,6 and ipod 5th gen). I am pretty sure that these devices use BLE so I cant understand what is wrong? Does anyone know? I am using the sniffer in UART mode by the way on windows 10 with nordic.

Thanks